# Ubuntu Linux -- create custom burnable/bootable DVD image?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I recently developed some kiosk software that runs on Ubuntu Linux, and my client needs me to set up ten more computers with the complete software package(and that number will only grow in the future).

So I'm looking for a way to make this less of a pain in the neck and prevent me from shooting myself in the foot -- I had to disable some things on the installations of the operating systems like screensavers, automatic updates, etc. that would pop up and disrupt the kiosk operation. I don't feel comfortable doing that by hand across 10 computers, it seems stupid.

Does anybody have recommendations for software that would let me burn an installable DVD with a complete image of the hard drive from one of the devices? I've looked at Clonezilla, G4L, and PartImage and I'm still not quite sure if any of them offer what I need. I know PartImage for sure won't work, because it doesn't support Ext4.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools such as Clonezilla and FOG that are for cloning dozens of machines at a time.  It works both locally (Clonezilla on a CD/DVD), and network (PXE boot FOG)...

Clonezilla - http://clonezilla.org/

FOG Project - http://www.fogproject.org/

Leave a comment if you need help setting one up...

**EDIT:** I SERIOUSLY do not recommend using a live CD...  It requires a lot of background work to get everything working, the tools listed in this post will create a bit-for-bit identical copy of your current setup on all workstation you deploy to...  A much easier solution over-all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do local storage when using a LiveCD, it uses the RAM to create a temporary file system. This data won't persist after a reboot.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
shows how to customize a LiveCD

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872) that shows how to create a Ubuntu LiveCD from a running installation.

However, if all you want to do is clone a system, then I would use something like Clonezilla for making exact duplicates.  You'll probably need to update networking configuration after cloning (e.g., hostname, IP, etc.) but you'll get the "most identical" system.  The LiveCD directions are better if you want different user accounts, timezones, etc. on each system.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [RemasterSys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html) would be an option... haven't used it yet personally, but one of the options (dist) is supposed to be for making a custom install CD (minus personal info) which sounds about right for your needs..